# which statment in the while loop will be performed first?

Tags: c, string, pointers, while-loop, char

In this sample program,in the while loop which part will be done first(increment,assignment,test condition).

```
int main()
{

char s[]="lumps,bumps,swollen veins,new pains";
char t[40]={};
char *ss,*tt;
tt=t;
ss=s;
while(*tt++ = *ss++);
printf("%s\n",t);
return 0;
}
```

The output of the following program is :

```
lumps,bumps,swollen veins,new pains
```

Can someone tell me how this program is giving the output and how the while statment is working

if i am correct first the *ss++ will be done so that the ss will point to the value 'u' and then it will assign to *tt++  i.e(t[1]).so if it is like this the output should be "umps,bumps,swollen veins,new pains" . The L should not be printed but why L is also printing

Comment: Why don't you run it and find out? Or look it up?

Comment: And why write code that is so unreadable that even a person of your stature cannot understand it

Comment: I'd say this `*tt++` provokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @alk no *tt++ will be treated as *(tt++)

Comment: @Walter: Sure, but it referrs to `t` which's elements hadn't been initialised.

Comment: @Walter really why are you writing code that is difficult to understand?

Comment: @EdHeal Dude it just a simple code,whats wrong with you ,i dont find any difficul part in it :P

Comment: @walter - If it was so simple then why have you posted this question?!

Comment: This is the K&R `strcpy()`.

Comment: ... with an addtional, inproperly used `printf()`. @wildplasser

Comment: ... which now has been edited out by @Walter .

Comment: @alk, the elements of `t` don't have to be initialized, this is only the left side of the assignment. Also, now this code is invalid, `{}` is not a valid initializer.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Not my day. Cleaning up. Thanks anyway for notifing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take into account

1) priorities of the operators;
2) and that the order of evalutions of subexpressions for some operators is unspecified.
3) results of the operations

The priorities of the operators are following

1) postincrement operator ++
2) dereferencing *
3) assignment

That it would be more clear you could substitute loop

```
while(*tt++ = *ss++);
```

for this one

```
while( *tt = *ss )
{
    ++tt;
    ++ss;
}
```

The difference between them is that in the second loop tt and ss will not be incremented if *ss assigned to *tt is equalt to the terminating zero '\0'.

And for understanding the last loop in turn can be rewritten as

```
while( *tt = *ss, *tt != '\0' )
{
    ++tt;
    ++ss;
}
```

where there is used the comma operator in the condition

All that you should understand is that the value of the postfix ++ operator is the value of its operand **before incrementing**.

Comment: if i am correct first the *ss++ will be done so that the ss will point to the value 'u' and then it will assign to *tt++(t[1]).so if  it is like this the output should be "umps,bumps,swollen veins,new pains" . The L should not be printed but why L is also printing

Comment: @Walter because that's how post-increment works. What you describe would happen with pre-increment.

Comment: @Walter I think it will be enough if you will understand that the result of expression ss++ is the value of ss before incrementing.

Answer (score 1):

In the above program, I have written full description of the process.

Please see that below :

[image]

Also :

[image]

Comment: i dnt think s is the array of block of char.it is not 2-D array. it is a single 1-D array

Comment: Yeah, I know and I haven't written about the 2-D Array anywhere Walter..The boxes I have drawn are in a single line and that means 1- Dimension

Answer (score 0):

Its not the way it behaves. As you are using post increment, fisrt of all *ss will get ss[0] from string and assign it in *tt (tt[0]), then pointers will increment and in next iteration ss[1] will be copied into tt[1] and so on. So in tt string, you will get exactly same string as you have in ss